# Enable Apache serve of one specific directory under a web domain

Tags: linux, apache

How can i enable access to one specific directory : `www.mysite.com/mydir`

Today i try to access but i get a `403 forbidden message.`

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /mydir/index.html on this server.
```

There is an .htaccess file i can drop into the mydir directory to enable the index.html fiel to be served by apache server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell:

```
$ chmod 755 mydir
$ chmod -R go+r mydir
```